# How can I set desktop.ini ACL to allow me to delete it?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to delete some users from AD and also  take out their home directories. However, we have a script that denies us Administrators rights to their desktop.ini's because that stops their folder name being resolved in Explorer. However, when I want to blow out their whole home directory, the fact that there desktop.ini is still there means the parent folder can't be deleted either. I thought the below script would give me rights but it hasn't. What am I missing guys?

```
        If (Test-Path  $homeDir) { 
            $user = $_.uname 
            Set-ItemProperty -Path "\\server\students\home\$user" -Name Attributes -Value "Normal"
            $acl = Get-Acl "\\server\students\home\$user"
            $acl.access | where-object {$_.AccessControlType -eq "Deny"} | Foreach-object { $acl.RemoveAccessRule($_) }
            (Get-Item "\\server\students\home\$user").SetAccessControl($acl)
            Get-ChildItem -Path "\\server\students\home\$user\*" -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
            Remove-Item "\\server\students\home\$user" -Recurse
            Write-host "$user's home directory deleted successfully"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's external to PowerShell (runs within PS just fine though) but I would suggest using icalcs as it makes this much simpler...

```
icacls "\\server\students\home\$user" /grant administrators:F /t
```

Comment: That looked perfect, and ran perfectly too but still no joy. I even tried using takeown before icacls, and they both execute without errors, but as soon as it hits Remove-Item I get the 'not enough permission to perform action' error (even though I can delete the file manually?)

Comment: Hm, I wonder if it's moving on in the script and trying to delete the file before icacls finishes? I can't remember if PowerShell waits for external commands to complete before moving on in the script.